# How to import a CSV in Azure SQL Database using a python script calling an API

Tags: sql, database, azure

I have a python script calling an API and returning a csv file. I would like to import this data in an Azure SQL Database, with a batch reload every 30 minutes.
I can't find anything about automatic import with scripts in Azure, is it possible ?
Thanks for any help !

Comment: You should always provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Where the csv file stored?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Python SQL SDK to do it.

Or you can use Azure Blob Storage SDK and upload results there and with use of logic apps and BCP automatically upload data into azure SQL.

Here is example on how to do it https://marczak.io/posts/azure-loading-csv-to-sql/

Alternatively you can easily load data from blob storage into database using Azure data Factory, you can example find here: https://azure4everyone.com/posts/2019/07/data-factory-intro/